# Mac OS X app bundle for shell script doesn't works

Tags: macos, shell, osx-lion, nsbundle

I just did a app bundle like it's shown on [this blog](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps), but the app is not working. It looks like it will open (the OS X effect of the app opening) but then nothing happens, no window, no process, nothing. Running the script as `./app.sh` on app directory works perfectly and opens app window. The steps i'm doing are:

1. Copy appify script to my app directory.
2. Run appify. Generates `My App.app` with shell script inside of `Contents/MacOS/` and `Info.plist` file on `Contents/`.
3. As my app needs other files, i copy my `data/` directory onto app bundle directory `Contents/MacOS/data/`.

I tried using appify script shown in the blog post and also [the updated one](https://github.com/subtleGradient/tilde-bin/blob/master/appify). I also tried `chmod +x` on both, the .app bundle and the .sh inside of `My App.app/Contents/MacOS/`.

I'm lost on how to make the bundle run my app. Any clues on this?

Comment: Is there anything in the `Console` app that indicates a launch error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need appify to create a script that can be executed with a mouse click (like an app), just follow this simple procedure:

1. Create your script file (ex. myscript)
2. Give it execution permissions (chmod 755 ./myscript)
3. Contextual menu on the script file -> Get Info -> Open with: -> (Associate: Application->Utilities->Terminal app)
4. Contextual menu on the script file -> Get Info -> (Put the icon you want by drag/drop your icon file on the high left corner little icon)